# ¿Por qué sale el error "Inconsistencia de tipos" al crear Word en C# 2022?

Tags: c#

Me sale el error **"Inconsistencia de tipos"** en la línea:

```
Word.Range díaemision = document.Bookmarks.Add(mydiaemision, ref diaemision1).Range;
```

Este es el fragmento del código donde ocurre el error:

```
 if (DgvCotizaciones.CurrentRow==null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe ubicarse en una fila");
                return;
            }
            CotizacionesVi cotizacionesVi = cotizacionesViBindingSource.Current as CotizacionesVi;
            Cotizacione cotizacione = CotizacionBL.GetById(cotizacionesVi.IdCotizacion);
            System.Reflection.Missing missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Word.Application applicationWord=new Word.Application();
            string ruta = Application.StartupPath + @"\PlantillaCotizacion.dotx";
            Word.Document document = applicationWord.Documents.Open(ruta, missing);
            object diaemision1 = "diaemision";
            var mydiaemision = cotizacione.Fecha.ToString("dddd");
            Word.Range díaemision = document.Bookmarks.Add(mydiaemision, ref diaemision1).Range;
            object mesemision1 = "mesemision";
            var mymesemision =  cotizacione.Fecha.ToString("MMMM");
            Word.Range mesemsion = document.Bookmarks.Add(mymesemision, ref mesemision1).Range;


            applicationWord.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: Te serviría de mucho agregar una sentencia **Try-Catch** en tu código
``try 
{
    // Aquí puedes poner el fragmento del código
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Console:WriteLine("Ha ocurrido un error: {}",ex.Message);
}``
Para mostrar el mensaje de error.

Comment: Para trabajar con documentos word te recomiendo q hagas uso de la libreria DocX, es muy sencilla y te abstrae de las complejidades de tener q hacerlo como ahora, ademas de todo el codigo q te vas a ahorrar

Comment: Gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta.